# NextJS Head component renders stale props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

My goal is to try and put this tag in my NextJS' app's head:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com" />`

I have set up a custom `_app.js`, and in the getInitialProps I return my URL by using the `url` package. This works fine and I get the url on page load. This is the code for this:

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const initialProps = {};

    if (isServer) {
        const { req: { url: pageUrl, headers: { host } } } = ctx;

        initialProps.canonicalHref =
        createUrl({subdomain: host.split('.')[0], pathname: url.parse(pageUrl).pathname});
    }

    return  { ...initialProps }
}
```

And in my render function I use this to render the link tag:

```
        <Head>
          <link rel="canonical" href={canonicalHref || location.host + router.asPath} key="canonical" />
        </Head>
```

The idea is that getInitialProps returns the first value, then on the client side it returns null, making it fall back to `location.host + router.asPath`.

The only problem is that router.asPath seems to be one step behind the actual value whenever it updates. For example say if I'm on 'http://bla.com/two' and my previous page was 'http://bla.com/one' then the link will render as `<link rel="canonical" href="http://bla.com/one" />`.

I hope I've explained myself well enough here and I hope someone has any ideas to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's in the render then just use `location.href` instead of `location.host + router.asPath` also if you want to know more about why [router.asPath shows previous URL](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4369)

Comment: I will try this soon, would you recommend updating my next version then? Since ti seems the previous URL issue has been resolved in a future PR. I'm reluctant to update major because of breaking changes on quite a large app, but I will make it a priority if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I replaced the `location.host + router.asPath`, I still get the same issue with the old HREF being rendered in the tag, however I found something interesting: when I remove `key="canonical"` from the link tag, I get two canonical links rendered, one with the old url and another with the new

Comment: @CarwynStephen I can't think of a reason for why something like this will happen (there is no loop there so why are adding the key attribute). As for updating nextjs I don't think it's necessary in your case

Comment: I add the key here because elements can be added to NextJS' Head component from multiple locations, and the Head component relies on keys to know how to render unique components. If you look at the `unique()` function [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next-server/lib/head.js) you can see how it uses the key

Comment: Turns out that updating Next from 6.1.1-canary.0 to 7.0.2 did indeed solve my issue, now to fix a bunch of tests and manually test everything, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @CarwynStephen I haven't done anything, thanks to you I learnt new things.

Comment: you poined me to that pull request, which suggested that my issue had been fixed in a later version of Next, hence making me update Next ;)